# scdf2 uaa request failed redirect to dashboard from login

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, cloudfoundry-uaa

Using kubernetes deployer, I cannot get login into scdf2 applying uaa service security... using scdf 2.1.2 image version.

I got a loop into /login and /login?code=xxx from uaa service because, I think, scdf2 cannot get "token"..

The process :

1) Initial launching of uaa server .

An uaa service running into a pod k8s, using the following config 
[applying https://github.com/making/uaa-on-kubernetes/blob/master/k8s/uaa.yml]

It needs a secret deployed with cert and key. 
When i've created the csr, with CN value for certificated is "uaa-service"
as a valid hostname
Then, uaa-service using https and certs:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: uaa-service
  labels:
    app: uaa
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8443
    nodePort: 8443  
    name: uaa
  selector:
    app: uaa    
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: uaa
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: uaa
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: uaa
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - image: openjdk:8-jdk-slim
        name: pem-to-keystore
        volumeMounts:
        - name: keystore-volume
          mountPath: /keystores
        - name: uaa-tls
          mountPath: /uaa-tls
        command:          
        - sh
        - -c
        - |
          openssl pkcs12 -export \
                  -name uaa-tls \
                  -in /uaa-tls/tls.crt \
                  -inkey /uaa-tls/tls.key \
                  -out /keystores/uaa.p12 \
                  -password pass:foobar
          keytool -importkeystore \
                  -destkeystore /keystores/uaa.jks \
                  -srckeystore /keystores/uaa.p12 \
                  -deststoretype pkcs12 \
                  -srcstoretype pkcs12 \
                  -alias uaa-tls \
                  -deststorepass changeme \
                  -destkeypass changeme \
                  -srcstorepass foobar \
                  -srckeypass foobar \
                  -noprompt
      containers:
      - name: uaa
        image: making/uaa:4.13.0
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - |
          mv /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/uaa.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war 
          catalina.sh run
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8443
        volumeMounts:
        - name: uaa-config
          mountPath: /uaa
          readOnly: true
        - name: server-config
          mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
          subPath: server.xml
          readOnly: true
        - name: keystore-volume
          mountPath: /keystores
          readOnly: true
        env:
        - name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
          value: "-Djava.security.policy=unlimited -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8443
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 90
          timeoutSeconds: 30
          failureThreshold: 50
          periodSeconds: 60
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8443
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 90
          timeoutSeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 60
          failureThreshold: 50
      volumes:
      - name: uaa-config
        configMap:
          name: uaa-config
          items:
          - key: uaa.yml
            path: uaa.yml
          - key: log4j.properties
            path: log4j.properties
      - name: server-config
        configMap:
          name: uaa-config
          items:
          - key: server.xml
            path: server.xml
      - name: keystore-volume
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: uaa-tls
        secret:
          secretName: uaa-tls
          # kubectl create secret tls uaa-tls --cert=uaa-service.crt --key=uaa-service.key
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: uaa-config
data:
  server.xml: |-
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <Server port="-1">
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
      <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector class="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000"
                   scheme="https"
                   port="8443"
                   SSLEnabled="true"
                   sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
                   ciphers="TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
                   secure="true"
                   clientAuth="false"
                   sslProtocol="TLS"
                   keystoreFile="/keystores/uaa.jks"
                   keystoreType="PKCS12"
                   keyAlias="uaa-tls"
                   keystorePass="changeme"
                   bindOnInit="false"/>
        <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   port="8989"
                   address="127.0.0.1"
                   bindOnInit="true"/>
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
          <Host name="localhost"
                appBase="webapps"
                unpackWARs="true"
                autoDeploy="false"
                failCtxIfServletStartFails="true">
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
                   remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
                   protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"                   internalProxies="10\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|192\.168\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|169\.254\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|127\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|172\.1[6-9]{1}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|172\.2[0-9]{1}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|172\.3[0-1]{1}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"/>
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                   prefix="localhost_access" suffix=".log" rotatable="false" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>
          </Host>
        </Engine>
      </Service>
    </Server>
  log4j.properties: |-
    PID=????
    log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] uaa%X{context} - ${PID} [%t] .... %5p --- %c{1}: %m%n
    log4j.category.org.springframework.security=INFO
    log4j.category.org.cloudfoundry.identity=INFO
    log4j.category.org.springframework.jdbc=INFO
    log4j.category.org.apache.http.wire=INFO
  uaa.yml: |-
    logging:
      config: "/uaa/log4j.properties"
    require_https: true
    scim:
      groups:
        zones.read: Read identity zones
        zones.write: Create and update identity zones
        idps.read: Retrieve identity providers
        idps.write: Create and update identity providers
        clients.admin: Create, modify and delete OAuth clients
        clients.write: Create and modify OAuth clients
        clients.read: Read information about OAuth clients
        clients.secret: Change the password of an OAuth client
        scim.write: Create, modify and delete SCIM entities, i.e. users and groups
        scim.read: Read all SCIM entities, i.e. users and groups
        scim.create: Create users
        scim.userids: Read user IDs and retrieve users by ID
        scim.zones: Control a user's ability to manage a zone
        scim.invite: Send invitations to users
        password.write: Change your password
        oauth.approval: Manage approved scopes
        oauth.login: Authenticate users outside of the UAA
        openid: Access profile information, i.e. email, first and last name, and phone number
        groups.update: Update group information and memberships
        uaa.user: Act as a user in the UAA
        uaa.resource: Serve resources protected by the UAA
        uaa.admin: Act as an administrator throughout the UAA
        uaa.none: Forbid acting as a user
        uaa.offline_token: Allow offline access
    oauth:
      clients:
        uaa_admin:
          authorities: clients.read,clients.write,clients.secret,uaa.admin,scim.read,scim.write,password.write
          authorized-grant-types: client_credentials
          override: true
          scope: 'cloud_controller.read,cloud_controller.write,openid,password.write,scim.userids,dataflow.view,dataflow.create,dataflow.manage'
          secret: uaa_secret
          id: uaa_admin
      user:
        authorities:
          - openid
          - scim.me
          - cloud_controller.read
          - cloud_controller.write
          - cloud_controller_service_permissions.read
          - password.write
          - scim.userids
          - uaa.user
          - approvals.me
          - oauth.approvals
          - profile
          - roles
          - user_attributes
          - uaa.offline_token
    issuer:
      uri: https://uaa-service:8443
    login:
      url: https://uaa-service:8443
      entityBaseURL: https://uaa-service:8443
      entityID: cloudfoundry-saml-login
      saml:
        nameID: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified'
        assertionConsumerIndex: 0
        signMetaData: true
        signRequest: true
        socket:
          connectionManagerTimeout: 10000
          soTimeout: 10000
      authorize:
        url: https://uaa-service:8443/oauth/authorize
    uaa:
      # The hostname of the UAA that this login server will connect to
      url: https://uaa-service:8443
      token:
        url: https://uaa-service:8443/oauth/token
      approvals:
        url: https://uaa-service:8443/approvals
      login:
        url: https://uaa-service:8443/authenticate
      limitedFunctionality:
        enabled: false
        whitelist:
          endpoints:
            - /oauth/authorize/**
            - /oauth/token/**
            - /check_token/**
            - /login/**
            - /login.do
            - /logout/**
            - /logout.do
            - /saml/**
            - /autologin/**
            - /authenticate/**
            - /idp_discovery/**
          methods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - OPTIONS
```

I think that rhe important values to remember  are ( in doubt about saml):

```
    issuer:
      uri: https://uaa-service:8443
    login:
      url: https://uaa-service:8443
      entityBaseURL: https://uaa-service:8443
      authorize:
        url: https://uaa-service:8443/oauth/authorize
    uaa:
      # The hostname of the UAA that this login server will connect to
      url: https://uaa-service:8443
      token:
        url: https://uaa-service:8443/oauth/token
      approvals:
        url: https://uaa-service:8443/approvals
      login:
        url: https://uaa-service:8443/authenticate
```

Ok, deployed and running the pod. Remember 8443 form uaa_services actions.

2) 
Upgrade uaa config for users admin and user and roles mappings.

Because i cannot get install uaac gem ... i run a docker imagen with uaac client:

`docker run --rm -it cf-uaac bash`

then

```
>>>>  I need add the ip pod uaa-server to the docker image 
#echo "10.42.0.1   uaa-service" >> /etc/hosts  
#uaac --skip-ssl-validation   target https://uaa-service:8443
Unknown key: Max-Age = 86400
Target: http://uaa-service:8443
#uaac token client get uaa_admin  -s uaa_secret
Unknown key: Max-Age = 86400
Successfully fetched token via client credentials grant.
Target: http://uaa-service:8443
Context: uaa_admin, from client uaa_admin
>>>  Ok i got a uaa_admin token to create admin user, group etc ..
>>>  check token again is valid
# uaac token decode
Note: no key given to validate token signature
  jti: 8067e0122b20433ab817f684e7335d30
  sub: uaa_admin
  authorities: clients.read password.write clients.secret clients.write uaa.admin scim.write scim.read
  scope: clients.read password.write clients.secret clients.write uaa.admin scim.write scim.read
  client_id: uaa_admin
  cid: uaa_admin
  azp: uaa_admin
  grant_type: client_credentials
  rev_sig: 7216b9b8
  iat: 1565017183
  exp: 1565060383
  iss: http://uaa-service:8443/oauth/token
  zid: uaa
  aud: scim uaa_admin password clients uaa**
#uaac user add admin -p password --emails admin@mk.com
root@bf98436ccc82:/# uaac user add admin -p password --emails admin@mk.com
user account successfully added
root@bf98436ccc82:/# uaac user add user  -p password --emails user@mk.com
user account successfully added

=========================================================================================================================================
root@bf98436ccc82:/# uaac group add "dataflow.view"
  id: 9796f596-e540-4f3b-a32c-90b1bac5d0cc
  meta
    version: 0
    created: 2019-08-05T15:00:01.014Z
    lastmodified: 2019-08-05T15:00:01.014Z
  members:
  schemas: urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0
  displayname: dataflow.view
  zoneid: uaa
root@bf98436ccc82:/# uaac group add "dataflow.create"

  id: c798e762-bcae-4d1f-8eef-2f7083df2d45
  meta
    version: 0
    created: 2019-08-05T15:00:01.495Z
    lastmodified: 2019-08-05T15:00:01.495Z
  members:
  schemas: urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0
  displayname: dataflow.create
  zoneid: uaa
root@bf98436ccc82:/# uaac group add "dataflow.manage"
  id: 47aeba32-db27-456c-aa12-d5492127fe1f
  meta
    version: 0
    created: 2019-08-05T15:00:01.986Z
    lastmodified: 2019-08-05T15:00:01.986Z
  members:
  schemas: urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0
  displayname: dataflow.manage
  zoneid: uaa

=========================================================================================================================================
root@bf98436ccc82:/# uaac member add dataflow.view admin
success
root@bf98436ccc82:/# uaac member add dataflow.create admin
success
root@bf98436ccc82:/# uaac member add  dataflow.manage admin
success
=========================================================================================================================================
root@bf98436ccc82:/# uaac member add dataflow.view user
success
root@bf98436ccc82:/# uaac member add dataflow.create user
success
root@bf98436ccc82:/# uaac member add  dataflow.manage user
success

>>>  Now, mapping admin to dataflow uua client 
>>>  Important
>>>  The redirect url MUST THE SAME from http original request
>>>  scdf2-data-flow-skipper:8844 
>>>   this is my login uri to dashboard scdf2 
>>>  i can't get direct connect to pod ... ssh tunnels insteads ..

# uaac client add dataflow \
   --name dataflow \
   --scope cloud_controller.read,cloud_controller.write,openid,password.write,scim.userids,dataflow.view,dataflow.create,dataflow.manage \
   --authorized_grant_types password,authorization_code,client_credentials,refresh_token \
   --authorities uaa.resource \
   --redirect_uri  http://scdf2-data-flow-server:8844/login\
   --autoapprove openid \
   --secret dataflow


#uaac client add skipper \
   --name skipper \
   --scope cloud_controller.read,cloud_controller.write,openid,password.write,scim.userids,dataflow.view,dataflow.create,dataflow.manage \
   --authorized_grant_types password,authorization_code,client_credentials,refresh_token \
   --authorities uaa.resource \
   --redirect_uri http://scdf2-data-flow-skipper:8844/login \
   --autoapprove openid \
   --secret skipper

>>>> Using curl to get a valid token and check that uri's are ok

curl -k -v -d"username=admin&password=password&client_id=dataflow&grant_type=client_credentials" -u "dataflow:dataflow" https://uaa-service:8443/oauth/token                                * Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x5632e4386dd0)

*   Trying 10.42.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x5632e4386dd0)
* Connected to uaa-service (10.42.0.1) port 8443 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'dataflow'
> POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: uaa-service:8443
> Authorization: Basic ZGF0YWZsb3c6ZGF0YWZsb3c=
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 81
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 81 out of 81 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 05 Aug 2019 15:02:21 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host uaa-service left intact
{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImxlZ2FjeS10b2tlbi1rZXkiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJqdGkiOiJlNmU3YzNiOWVkMmM0ZmI5ODQ5OWE3MmQ2N2EzMjMyYSIsInN1YiI6ImRhdGFmbG93IiwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsidWFhLnJlc291cmNlIl0sInNjb3BlIjpbInVhYS5yZXNvdXJjZSJdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJkYXRhZmxvdyIsImNpZCI6ImRhdGFmbG93IiwiYXpwIjoiZGF0YWZsb3ciLCJncmFudF90eXBlIjoiY2xpZW50X2NyZWRlbnRpYWxzIiwicmV2X3NpZyI6IjFkMmUwMjVjIiwiaWF0IjoxNTY1MDE3MzQxLCJleHAiOjE1NjUwNjA1NDEsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly91YWEtc2VydmljZTo4MDgwL29hdXRoL3Rva2VuIiwiemlkIjoidWFhIiwiYXVkIjpbImRhdGFmbG93IiwidWFhIl19.G2f8bIMbUWJOz8kcZYtU37yYhTtMOEJlsrvJFINnUjo","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":43199,"scope":"uaa.resource","jti":"e6e7c3b9ed2c4fb98499a72d67a3232a"}root@bf98436ccc82:/#
```

At this point, it seems that uaa server it is running ok and i can get from a "docker" process... let's continue using pods ...

3) Deploy skipper and scdf2 using security uaa.

Skipper and scdf2 are deployed using same values (changes into client_ide values of course:

```
LOGGING_LEVEL_ROOT: DEBUG
KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE: (v1:metadata.namespace)
SERVER_PORT: 8080
SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_ENABLED: false
SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_ANALYTICS_ENABLED: false
SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_SECRETS_ENABLE_API: true
SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_SCHEDULES_ENABLED: true
SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_SECRETS_PATHS: /etc/secrets
SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_CONFIG_NAME: scdf2-data-flow-server
SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_CLIENT_SERVER_URI: http://${SCDF2_DATA_FLOW_SKIPPER_SERVICE_HOST}/api
SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_SERVER_URI: http://${SCDF2_DATA_FLOW_SERVER_SERVICE_HOST}:${SCDF2_DATA_FLOW_SERVER_SERVICE_PORT}
SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_SECURITY_CF_USE_UAA: true
SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_CLIENT_ID: dataflow
SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_CLIENT_SECRET: dataflow
SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SCOPE: openid
SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_SECURITY_AUTHORIZATION_MAP_OAUTH_SCOPES: true
SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN_URI: https://uaa-service:8443/oauth/token
SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_USER_AUTHORIZATION_URI: https://uaa-service:8443/oauth/authorize
SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCE_USER_INFO_URI: https://uaa-service:8443/userinfo
SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCE_TOKEN_INFO_URI: https://uaa-service:8443/check_token
SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: { "com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation": "false", "maven": { "local-repository": "myLocalrepoMK", "remote-repositories": { "mk-repository": {"url": "http://${NEXUS_SERVICE_HOST}:${NEXUS_SERVICE_PORT}/repository/maven-releases/","auth": {"username": "admin","password": "admin123"}},"spring-repo": {"url": "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release","auth": {"username": "","password": ""}},"spring-repo-snapshot": {"url": "https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/","auth": {"username": "","password": ""}}}} }

Using 8443 as comunication between pod to pod ...
```

And skipper and scdf2 config maps:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /management
  security:
    roles: MANAGE
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      security:
        authorization:
          map-oauth-scopes: true                                 
          role-mappings:
            ROLE_CREATE: dataflow.create                          
            ROLE_DEPLOY: dataflow.deploy
            ROLE_DESTROY: dataflow.destoy
            ROLE_MANAGE: dataflow.manage
            ROLE_MODIFY: dataflow.modify
            ROLE_SCHEDULE: dataflow.schedule
            ROLE_VIEW: dataflow.view
          enabled: true
          rules:
            # About
            - GET    /about                          => hasRole('ROLE_VIEW')
            # Audit                
            - GET /audit-records                     => hasRole('ROLE_VIEW')
            - GET /audit-records/**                  => hasRole('ROLE_VIEW')                
            # Boot Endpoints                
            - GET /management/**                  => hasRole('ROLE_MANAGE')
```

At this point, i think why cannot i see a login mapping defined?
I deploy skipper and scdf2 and the first problem is that all health process is returno 401 .. ok ... let's continue ...

Request not progress after :

`http://scdf2-data-flow-server:8844/login?code=ETFX6qfQMw&state=Fudfts`

Not bypass /login page from scdf2 and go to dashboard

The request hangs in:

`http://scdf2-data-flow-server:8844/login&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=5HST0f`

I think that all UAA's process are terminanted and back to redirect to login into scdf security model.

[login and loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91U1f.png)

But, what is happens?

Login request arrive to scdf2, scdf2 check into uaa that all is correct and back again to process as new request into scdf2, that send again a request to uaa server ...

Then , restart scdf using debug logging ...
request is now :

`GET /login?code=W7luipeEGG&state=7yiI9S HTTP/1.1`

and logging :

```
2019-08-12 15:37:58.413 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@39c5463b:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@6160a9db:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:58562]], Read from buffer: [0]
2019-08-12 15:37:58.414 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@39c5463b:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@6160a9db:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:58562]], Read direct from socket: [593]
2019-08-12 15:37:58.414 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [GET /login?code=W7luipeEGG&state=7yiI9S HTTP/1.1
Host: scdf2-data-flow-server:8844
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: JSESSIONID=077168452F9CCF4378715DC3FE20D4B2

]
2019-08-12 15:37:58.414 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.t.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor   : Cookies: Parsing b[]: JSESSIONID=077168452F9CCF4378715DC3FE20D4B2
2019-08-12 15:37:58.414 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter     :  Requested cookie session id is 077168452F9CCF4378715DC3FE20D4B2
2019-08-12 15:37:58.414 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request GET /login
2019-08-12 15:37:58.414 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
2019-08-12 15:37:58.414 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    :  Not subject to any constraint
2019-08-12 15:37:58.415 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set encoding to UTF-8
2019-08-12 15:37:58.415 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Decoding query null UTF-8
2019-08-12 15:37:58.416 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Start processing with input [code=W7luipeEGG&state=7yiI9S]
2019-08-12 15:37:58.425 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.c.c.s.OAuthSecurityConfiguration     : An error occurred while accessing an authentication REST resource.
```

but using debug error, now i can see:

```
019-08-12 15:37:58.416 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Start processing with input [code=W7luipeEGG&state=7yiI9S]
2019-08-12 15:37:58.425 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.c.c.s.OAuthSecurityConfiguration     : An error occurred while accessing an authentication REST resource.
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token
      at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
        at 
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:105)
        ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://uaa-service:8443/oauth/token": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:744)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:691)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:137)
        ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
               at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
        ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
        ... 94 common frames omitted
2019-08-12 15:37:58.426 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
2019-08-12 15:37:58.427 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :  Disabling the response for further output
```

Ok, now we got

`sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

It seems that jvm needs more info into cacerts o similars ...

then, how can i add the new cacert from uaa-server to jvm from scdf2?

Is it the new step into get to start working scdf2 uaa ?

what am i doing wrong?

Do I need to add the uaa-service cert to pod jvm from scdf2 running?

please help !!!

Comment: Hi. Sorry that you're having trouble with this. Would you be able to share more details about how you have UAA up and running in K8s? Perhaps also share your deployment YAMLs, so we can review the end to end aspects of it.

Comment: Hi @SabbyAnandan. Please, if you can help me to fix the problem... if you needs more info, i'll post it as soon as you need..

Comment: Yes, please. If you can share the steps and the deployment YAMLs of SCDF, UAA and others, we can review it on our side.

Comment: Oh, never mind. I see the updates now. We will review it.

Comment: 19/08. Debug logging for all apps. scdf shows now that there is a problem with ua-svc. I've add the cacert from uaa to keystore, and i can login. but, roles failed.!

Comment: Btw, these days property binding via environment variables should not use underscores in property names, i.e. `SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN_URI` should be `SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ACCESSTOKENURI`

Answer (score 0):

And, the problem was,

Into the server-deployment, I've remove the following config:

```
#- name: SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SCOPE
#  value: 'openid'
```

Do not apply any config parametrization about scope in anywhere.

Because, if scope is omitted or null, all scopes will be assigned to the client, and no needed confirmation for third party permission ...

Warning, you can get alot samples using this config into .. tested?

No apply any config about uaa into skipper.... only cacert to uaa into jks