# login loop issue while integrating keycloak with spring cloud dataflow

Tags: spring, keycloak, spring-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I am trying to integrate keycloak with spring cloud dataflow following the steps as mentioned in
https://github.com/jvalkeal/randomstuff/tree/master/dataflow-keycloak, after successful login the redirection doesn't point to the configured url, it redirects back to the login page. (same issue as mentioned in [scdf2 uaa request failed redirect to dashboard from login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57376292/scdf2-uaa-request-failed-redirect-to-dashboard-from-login)).
what is it iam doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Change user-name-attribute from "user_name" to "preferred_username".